# Accessing query set object in django template with PK

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a related model with ForeignKey and can't figure out how to access it in template with pk. My models.py is given below for details.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)
    suppliers= models.ManyToManyField('Supplier', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    customer_service_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    shipping_charges = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name 
    def get_url(self):
    return reverse('provider_detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

product_detail.html

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.description }}
<img src="{{ object.image.url }}">
{{ object.price }}
```

I need to add supplier name in template how to do it with pk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Product model has multiple Suppliers (ManyToManyField), thus you will need a for loop to show all of them in the template.

```
{% for supplier in object.suppliers.all %}
   {{ supplier.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: However when I've added this {% with supplier=object.suppliers %}
                              <a href="{{ supplier.id }}">{{ supplier.name }}</a>
                              {% endwith %}. It shows "None" instead of name but I do have providers already added.

Comment: It needs to be `object.suppliers.all`.

Comment: @Alikhan if you use supplier=objects.suppliers then supplier is a queryset, not a Supplier object. This is because suppliers is a ManyToMany relationship, thus a Product can have multiple suppliers. I you want a Product to have only one Supplier, you should change the ManyToMany to a ForeignKey relationship.